# How to create a step waterfall inside the Virtual Assistant where the steps are AdaptiveCards that are generated at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, adaptive-cards

I need to generate the waterfall steps at runtime, as they are based off an API response - is this even possible with the `WaterfallDialog` and `WaterfallSteps`?

Creating the adaptive cards at runtime can be done using the `AdaptiveCard` class but in terms of adding these to the dialog stack can I just call `AddDialog()` at runtime and add the waterfall steps? My API returns JSON with the text to display in the dialog as well as what kind of controls it - it uses React-JSONSchema and the UISchema property as per [this documentation](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form-customization/#the-uischema-object). This is an external API that I am working with.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) for dialogs focuses on static content. Could I begin with an empty Waterfall and use something like [beginDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/dialogcontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#method-details) or will I have to do with a CustomDialog implementation?

Comment: @mdrichardson any brilliant ideas? :-)

Comment: Hello Matt, are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney thanks for checking in on this one, I didn't realise it was still unresolved. I managed to get it solved. I will post up my answer a bit later. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by using the [`ComplexDialogBot`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/blob/master/SDKV4-Samples/dotnet_core/ComplexDialogBot/ComplexDialogBot.cs) as the basis for how my bot would work.

More specifically inside the class linked above there are two methods of interest:

- `SelectionStepAsync` - Presents the user with a selection
- `LoopStepAsync` - Processes the user input and decides whether the current dialog flow should move to the next step, or be ended.

I created a `WaterfallStep[]` with two steps (`DisplayCardAsync` and `ProcessCardAsync`) which are analogous with the methods in the class above. In my case I had a collection of all the possible steps, along with the logic for figuring out whether completion criteria had been met for a flow which meant that all of the heavy lifting took place inside `ProcessCardAsync`.