# dynamically generate waterfall list

Tags: dialog, botframework, waterfall

In a Microsoft Bot, I want to build a generic dialog.
For this, I need to dynamically build the waterfall steps.

The idea:
From a MainDialog, call

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(GenericDialog), problemType);
```

In the constructor of GenericDialog:

```
 switch ( problemType)
    { 
       case problem1:
         BuildWaterfallList1();
         break;
       case "problem2:
         BuildWaterfallList2();
         break;
      etc...
    }
```

If we have 10 products and 10 problem types, all very similar, we don't want to have to create 100 different dialogs.

The issue we have with the approach above is that the parameter passed in the BeginDialogAsync is not accessible from the constructor of GenericDialog.

How can we achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a step waterfall inside the Virtual Assistant where the steps are AdaptiveCards that are generated at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453199/how-to-create-a-step-waterfall-inside-the-virtual-assistant-where-the-steps-are)

Comment: The title doesn't look the same, but the content is the same.

Comment: there is no clear solution in the article you mentions.

Comment: I have similar question posted here - [Multiple waterfall conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267723/multiple-waterfall-conversation-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

So how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

the final answer is that there is no way to use/dynamic waterfalls.

However, there are workarounds, other ways to achieve it.
In particular I used this example 
https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet

and managed to branch / loop to the next steps of my choice based on user input results.

Comment: Your link is broken. Could you please send the updated link?

Comment: @noobprogrammer Link is not broken. It was not properly formatted previously. Check now.